# New Git Experience in VS2019 Version 16.8.2: Can I compare a git branch before merging it with the current branch?

Tags: git, visual-studio

The scope of this question is New Git Experience in VS2019 Version 16.8.2.

[image]

Is there any way to compare a git branch before merging it into the current branch?

Is what I am asking aligns with normal git-flow, or is there a better way of comparing branches?